# Big difference in p-value from permutation test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, permutation-test

I have roughly 60 values of discrete temperature satisfaction votes ranging from 0 to 4. In the figure below I have grouped the votes depending on the daily number of hours the individual occupants are sitting at their desks. Now I want to make a permutation test, to show if there is any significant difference on the mean vote of occupants having up to 7.5 work hours per day at their workplace, and occupants having more than 7.5 work hours per day.

[image: Temperature satisfaction votes as a function of daily desk hours]

I have used the following code to carry out the one-tailed permutation test:

```
g1 <- subset(df, deskhours <= 7.5)$temperatureSatisfaction  # length = 13
g2 <- subset(df, deskhours > 7.5)$temperatureSatisfaction  # length = 43

k <- 100000

perms <- replicate(k, sample(c(g1, g2)))
my.mean.difs <- apply(perms[1:13, ], 2, mean) - apply(perms[14:56, ], 2, mean)
sum(my.mean.difs <= (mean(g1) - mean(g2))) / k
```

Actually I did not expect the use of `<=` or `<` (in the last line of the code) to make any significant difference on the p-value. However, I found that the use of `<=` gave me a p-value of 0.084, and the use of `<` gave me a p-value of 0.046. So, almost 4 % of the differences in means in the `my.mean.diffs` vector, is exactly equal to the actual difference between the two groups (`mean(g1) - mean(g2)`).

My logic says that it is very unlikely that the difference in means from the shuffled data, will hit exactly the observed difference in means. Am I wrong here? And which is the most correct sign to use: `<=` or `<`? With my significance level of 0.05, the conclusion is absolutely dependent on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My logic says that it is very unlikely that the difference in means from the shuffled data, will hit exactly the observed difference in means. Am I wrong here?

Yes, you're wrong - in that the observed difference may not be at all unlikely. The distribution of your response is discrete, so the distribution of the difference in means will be discrete, which means that you'll expect a number of other arrangements to produce the same mean difference.

> And which is the most correct sign to use: `<=` or `<`?

The definition of p-value is "the probability of a result at least as extreme as the one observed". Which is to say, when you work out the p-value, you include values equal to the observed one.

--

Why do you dichotomize the work hours?

Comment: The data comes from a questionnaire, where the occupants select a number representing the daily number of work hours. But I see the point in making the scale continuous.

Comment: Ok, It is more clear to me now. I thought the difference in means was continuer, due to the fact that it could take a value like -0.5527728--which is the difference in the observed means. But it makes sense that the difference in means not can be any value, since the original data are continuos. Thanks.

Comment: It's easier if you realize that (given the total of both samples is the same in every permutation), the difference in means is a linear function of the sum of the first sample. The sum of the first sample is the sum of 13 numbers from 4, 5, ... up to 9. It will either be an integer, or an integer $+\frac{1}{2}$. You might get a value like '92' or '89.5' for the sum of the values in the first sample ... and there's lots of ways to get a value like those. The distribution of the difference in means is identical, but scaled and shifted.

Comment: It not entirely correct. First, remember that it is the mean of the temperature satisfaction (values on y-axis) I use to calculate the difference in means. Not the number of hours at the work desk. Second, since the samples has the length of 13 and 43. The mean of the two groups will therefore be able to take a value different from an integer or an integer + 0.5. However, the number of possible means, is finite and discrete, because the distribution the means are coming from is discrete.

Comment: Sorry, you're right about me looking at the wrong variable but temp satisfaction is even easier - it's pure integer. The rest of the argument you appear to have misunderstood, so let me repeat it in terms of the correct $y$. Given the 13+43 observations, the **sum** of observations across both resamples is fixed. It immediately follows that the difference in mean temperature satisfaction is a linear function of the **sum** of temperature satisfaction in the first sample. The **sum** of temperature satisfaction in the first sample is integer. Therefore the difference in means must be discrete.